# How does the createFolds function in the caret package divide the dataset into K folds? Is it random sampling or stratified uniform sampling?

Tags: r-caret

How does the createFolds function in the caret package divide the dataset into K folds?  Is it random sampling or stratified uniform sampling?

Comment: this is answered within the [help of the corresponding function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-90/topics/createDataPartition): `When y is a factor in an attempt to balance the class distributions within the splits. For numeric y, the sample is split into groups sections based on percentiles and sampling is done within these subgroups. For createDataPartition, the number of percentiles is set via the groups argument. For createFolds and createMultiFolds, the number of groups is set dynamically based on the sample size and k...`